# how to check that user is logged in to facebook - php sdk

Tags: authentication, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

How I can determine that user is logged in to facebook but not authenticated my facebook web application using php sdk. I know we have **$user = $facebook->getUser();** but this only check that user authenticated the app or not. I want something like **FB.getLoginStatus**

1. the user is logged into Facebook and has authenticated your application (connected)
2. the user is logged into Facebook but has not authenticated your application (not_authorized)
3. the user is not logged into Facebook at this time and so we don't know if they've authenticated your application or not (unknown)

Want to determine second condition using php sdk i.e. of not_authorized but logged in to facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP SDK on it’s own has no way of knowing that.

The JS SDK can make cross-domain calls to have Facebook check if there is an active session under their domain. From server-side alone there is no way of doing something similar.

> I want something like FB.getLoginStatus

And why not use just that, and pass the info on to the server? (Cookie, AJAX, …)

Comment: I'm using this only at the moment. But was looking to do the same via php sdk. Anyways thanks for your help.